# Executing Selenium Webdriver scripts from ALM

Tags: selenium-webdriver, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

Requirement - To have best of both the world - Automation using Selenium webdriver (Java) and test management using QC/ALM.

Read that we can use ALM's Open Test Architecture (OTA) to run external scripts. Can someone please list down the steps?

Comment: QC and third party integration may be what you are looking for. Check this link http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/HP-QC-integration-with-3rd-party-test-automation-tool/m-p/2406708#M68523